# print function for stack c++

Tags: c++, stack

I am trying to print the contents of my stack. 
here is my code:
Stack.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;                            // specific commands from namespace std
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

typedef unsigned long Item;

class Stack
{
private:
    enum { MAX = 10 };  // MAX elements in this stack
    Item items[MAX];    // holds stack items
    int top;            // index for the top stack item
    int first, last;

public:
    Stack();
    Stack(int, int);
    ~Stack();
    void printCurr() const;
    void printCurrReverse() const;
    bool isempty() const;
    bool isfull() const;
    // return false if stack already full
    bool push(const Item& item);    // add item to stack
                                    // return false if stack already empty
    bool pop(Item& item);

};
```

stack.cpp

```
#pragma once
#include "Stack.h"
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;


Stack::Stack()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) //for loop that sets the initial array values to null
    {
        items[i] = 0;
    }   
    top = 0;
}


Stack::Stack(int first , int last)
{

    if (top <= 4)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            this -> items[i] = first;
        }
    }

    if (top >= 5 && top <= MAX)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= MAX; i++)
        {
            this -> items[i] = last;
        }
    }

}

Stack::~Stack()
{
}


void Stack::printCurr() const
{
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = index; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        cout << index + i;
    }
}

void Stack::printCurrReverse() const
{
    int index = top - 1;
    for (int i = index; i >= 0; i++)
    {
        cout << index + i;
    }
}



bool Stack::isempty() const
{
    return top == 0;
}

bool Stack::isfull() const
{
    return top == MAX;
}

bool Stack::push(const Item& item)
{
    if (top < MAX)
    {
        items[top++] = item;
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

bool Stack::pop(Item& item)
{
    if (top > 0)
    {
        item = items[--top];
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include "Stack.h"


using namespace std;

int main()
{

    Stack st1;

    char ch;
    unsigned long sc;
    cout << "Please Enter 'A' to Add A Score You Wish To Record, \n"
        << "Press R To Record A Score, V To View Recorded Scores & Q to Quit" << endl;
    while (cin >> ch && toupper(ch) != 'Q')
    {
        while (cin.get() != '\n')
            continue;
        if (!isalpha(ch))
        {
            cout << '\a';
            continue;
        }
        switch (ch)
        {
        case 'a':
        case 'A': cout << "Enter A Score To Add: ";
            cin >> sc;
            if (st1.isfull())
                cout << "stack already full\n";
            else
                st1.push(sc);
            break;
        case 'R':
        case 'r': if (st1.isempty())
            cout << "stack already empty\n";
                  else {
                      st1.pop(sc);
                      cout << "Score #" << sc << " popped\n";
                  }
                  break;
        case 'V':
        case 'v':

            cout << "Your Recorded Scores are : " << st1.printCurr() << endl;
            cout << "Your Recorded Scores In Reverse Order Are : " << st1.printCurrReverse() << endl;

            cout << "Please enter A to add a purchase order,\n"
                << "P to process a PO, or Q to quit.\n";
        }

        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

my problem is the print functions. I am getting the following error

```
Error C2679 binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'void' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
main.cpp 48
```

from what I understand this is happening because I am not overloading the `<<` operator correctly.

I need the print function to be with out parameters and without a return value.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the actual error message?

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error C2679 binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'void' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Answer (score 2):

Your print functions `printCurr` and `printCurrReverse` return void, and therefore cannot be used as parameter of `std::cout`  (in your `main`). Your functions already print it with cout.

You could let your function return string instead. Or remove them from the `cout` line.

The simplest way, put them out of the cout line:

```
cout << "Your Recorded Scores are : ";
st1.printCurr();
cout << "Your Recorded Scores In Reverse Order Are : "; 
st1.printCurrReverse();
```

Otherwise let your print functions return a `string` which you can create with `stringstream` for example:

```
std::string printCurrReverse() {
  stringstream strs;
  strs << " text "<< 33; //example
  return strs.str();
}
```

Comment: Or simply remove the `cout <<` part.

Comment: @Jpoor `st1.printCurr();`

Answer (score 0):

First of all this constructor

```
Stack::Stack(int first , int last)
{

    if (top <= 4)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            this -> items[i] = first;
        }
    }

    if (top >= 5 && top <= MAX)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= MAX; i++)
        {
            this -> items[i] = last;
        }
    }

}
```

does not make sense and has undefined behaviour because data member top is not initialized. And it is not clear what you are trying to do.

Function `printCurr` also does not make sense

```
void Stack::printCurr() const
{
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = index; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        cout << index + i;
    }
}
```

It simply outputs natural numbers in the range `[0, MAX - 1]`

If you mean to output the values stored in the stack then the function can look the following way

```
void Stack::printCurr() const
{
    for ( int i = top; i != 0; )
    {
        cout << items[--i];
    }
}
```

Correspondingly function `printCurrReverse` can look like

```
void Stack::printCurrReverse() const
{
    for ( int i = 0; i != top ; i++)
    {
        cout << items[i];
    }
}
```

Else as the functions have return type void you may not use them like

```
cout << "Your Recorded Scores In Reverse Order Are : " << st1.printCurrReverse() << endl;
```

If you want to use them such a way then they should be defined like

```
std::ostream & Stack::printCurr( std::ostream &os = std::cout ) const
{
    for ( int i = top; i != 0; )
    {
        os << items[--i];
    }

    return os;
}
```

and

```
std::ostream & Stack::printCurrReverse( std::ostream &os = std::cout ) const
{
    for ( int i = 0; i != top ; i++)
    {
        os << items[i];
    }

    return os;
}
```

Comment: For the first function I am trying to divide the stack into two separate integers.The first int contains the first five elements of the stack and the second int contains the last five elements of the stack.

Comment: @Jpoor In any case it is not clear what you are doing and what you are going to do with this.:)

Comment: I am trying to tell it to initialize int first for the first five elements of the stack and int last for the next five elements of the stack...

Comment: @Jpoor But the constructor does not do that. So for the reader it is not clear what it does.

Comment: @Jpoor Simply this constructor with parameters does not make any sense. I do not know what you are trying to do with this constructor. Agein data member top was not initialized.